# CoreLocation Authorization issues - never prompted for authorization

Tags: ios, core-location

I was testing out CoreLocation to learn how to capture and record the location of the user. I built a simple Master-Detail app which, in the detail pane, showed the user's live location. Everything worked as expected.

Next, I moved on to making my real app which also uses CoreLocation. I built the app with a Master-Detail style and also made it so that when the user opens the detail pane, it should show their current, live, location. However, nothing happens at all.

What I determined after a LOT of debugging and research is that as soon as my `locationManager` is created and I call `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` the authorization to *get* the location is changed to `denied` (or false, or whatever its called). The only way I can get live tracking is build and run the app in Xcode, once it opens in the simulator, open up Location Services and change the app setting to allow location tracking to "Always". Then I can see in the console that locations are being acquired.

I don't understand why I have to keep changing the authorization to "Always" over and over. I have deleted the app on the simulator, done a "clean" from XCode to start fresh, and still it starts on the simulator without authorization.

Anyone have ideas?

**UPDATE** Now I see that, when I build and it runs in the simulator, I get ONE location, then the authorization is changed to not allow location services.

Here's my code (which worked on another app):

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager : CLLocationManager!



func startTrackingLocation() {
    println("tracking engaged")
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() // <-- this was originally commented out
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    println("and we're tracking")
    println(locationManager.location)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("location acquired") // <--- Only see this when I manually allow location when app is running
    self.newLongLabel?.text = "\(locations[0].coordinate.longitude)"
    self.newLatLabel?.text = "\(locations[0].coordinate.latitude)"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.startTrackingLocation()
    self.configureView()
}

// more class stuff...
```

Comment: don’t request for the both in the same time, choose one: `requestAlwaysAuthorization` or `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` (I think you already have the both keys in plist)

Comment: @TonyMkenu - I removed the `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and it's not changed the situation. :/

Comment: Are you sure, that you have the key in plist? `<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>` or for Always?

Comment: @TonyMkenu Ya, sure do.

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: @MichaelDorner iOS 8

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain you have added the key to plist file try checking for it in the didChangeAuthorizationStatus: location manager delegate method.

Be sure you have both keys in plist as type string and with the values you would like to display to the user:

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status{

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways){

        if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
            [yourLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
            //run your code here
        }
    }
}
```